# Polynomial regression in Python (not working when list is not in order)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I made a program for polynomial regression, at fitting the best line. I have two lists, X and Y. Its working when list X is in order.

```
X = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
Y = np.array([2,3,8,13,20])
```

This is the graph when I get when list X is in order:[image]

But, if have values in list X, that are not in order, for example

```
X = np.array([1,5,3,4,2])
Y = np.array([2,3,8,13,20])
```

I get graph like this (not polynomial):
[image]

The important thing is that number 1 in X corresponds to number 2 in Y, number 5 in X corresponds to number 3 in Y and so on. What am I doing wrong? This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.array([1,5,3,4,2])
Y = np.array([2,3,8,13,20])
koeficienti = np.polyfit(X, Y, 2)

a=koeficienti[0]
b=koeficienti[1]
c=koeficienti[2]

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)

regression=[(a*x*x)+b*x + c for x in X] 

predX = float(input("Enter: ")) 
predY = (a * predX*predX ) + b*predX + c 

plt.scatter(X,Y) 
plt.scatter(predX, predY, color="red")vrednosti
plt.plot(X, regression) 
plt.grid() 

print("predvidjanje: ", round(predY,2))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Because the points simply do not follow a polynomial, what exactly do you expect?

Comment: I expect to get the best fit line based on the values that are in these two lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to plot the regression one would need to use a sorted array.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.array([1,5,3,4,2])
Y = np.array([2,3,8,13,20])
a,b,c = np.polyfit(X, Y, 2)

plt.scatter(X,Y) 

xval = np.linspace(np.min(X), np.max(X))
plt.plot(xval, a*xval**2+b*xval+c) 
plt.grid() 

plt.show()
```

[image]